# Como funciona el principio de JOptionPane para evitar que se ejecute código mientas está abierto

Tags: java, modal

Quiero saber como funciona el JOptionPane o cualquier mensaje de alerta, confirmación, etc. Porque quiero programar un frame que mientras no lo cierre, evite la ejecución del código que le sigue al abrir el frame

psdt: Quiero saber el principio o cual es la linea de código de un JOptionPane que evita la ejecución de las siguientes líneas de código hasta cerrar el JOptionPane. Si conozco para que usar el JOptionPane y sus atributos de entrada.

psdt2: La única etiqueta de esta pregunta es java

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver tu pregunta con [tag:c#]

Comment: Hola, debes quitar la etiqueta `c#` que no tiene nada que ver. Funciona así como vos bien decís (detiene la ejecución en ese punto donde se encuentra el `JOptionPane`) pero para tu suerte no hay que programar ningún frame, `JOptionPane` ya viene creado, solo hay que agregarle texto, ícono, etc. Ahí va un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues has elegido una pregunta muy interesante.

Lo primero como estás llamando un método estático, este se encarga de crear una instancia de JOptionPane para tí, por ejemplo en `showInputDialog` podrás ver

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, messageType,
              optionType, icon,
              options, initialValue);
```

Hasta allí nada raro<sup>1</sup>, luego de eso hace algunas cosas para el pintado, igual sin mucha magia allí.

Inmediatamente verás un

```
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title, style);
```

que es precisamente donde la magia empieza, pues como parte de `initDialog` tiene un window adapter para prevenir que se cierre

```
WindowAdapter adapter = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            setValue(null);
        }
```

Y para que si pierde el foco lo vuelva a ganar inmediatamente

```
 public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent we) {
            // Once window gets focus, set initial focus
            if (!gotFocus) {
                selectInitialValue();
                gotFocus = true;
            }
        }
```

Pero lo más interesante viene cuando investigas que la característica que buscas se llama modalidad, es decir si un comonente es modal o no.

Java incluye un [api de modalidad](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html) desde Java 6 para todo lo relacionado con JDialog definiendo varios tipos de dialogos modales posibles:

- Modeless, O dialogo no modal, te permitirá tener un dialogo no bloqueante.
- Document-modal, o modal por documento, bloquea todas las ventanas del mismo documento, excepto aquellas que en su jerarquía paarezcan como hijas
- Application-modal, o modal por aplicación, bloquea todas las ventanas de la misma aplicación excepto aquellas que en su jerarquía paarezcan como hijas
- Toolkit-modal, o modal por toolkit, bloquea todas las ventanas del mismo toolkit, excepto aquellas que en su jerarquía paarezcan como hijas

Cada uno de ellos se ve reflejado en los constructores de JDialog.

Como nota final, no olvides que algunas veces podrías encesitar usar alguna acción que requiera privilegios del sistema, es decir, [usando la clase AcessController](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html), tanto la clase JOptionPane como JDialog en algún momento pueden requerir dichos permisos para por ejemplo, acceder a una clase por reflección y llaamr a un método en particular.

## Referencias

- [Código de la clase](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17989512/)

## Notas

<sup>1</sup> como tal vez intuyas esa forma de creación es un patrón de diseño creacional pero es tema para otra ocasión

Answer (score -1):

- Mostrar un mensaje (el más simple)

El primer parámetro déjalo siempre `null`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se guardaron los cambios exitosamente!");
```

- Mostrar un mensaje con título en la barra superior + icono

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es posible realizar esta acción debido que..."
                +"\nCompruebe el...","Título de la ventana",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

En el último parámetro elegís la **constante de clase** para el icono que quieras. Por ejemplo el de precaución:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cuidado...","Título de la ventana",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Al escribir `JOptionPane.` el compilador te despliega todas las constantes.

- Mensaje de **confirmación**

```
int num = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Realmente desea eliminar este cliente?"
                + "\nCliente: x", "Confirmar Eliminar",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Esta ventana tiene dos botones, **si** y **no**. Si el usuario pulsa **si**, devolverá valor **0**, si pulsa **no** devolverá valor **1**, y si cierra la ventana devolverá **-1**.
Entonces controlas con un `if`, por ejemplo:

```
int num = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Realmente desea eliminar este cliente?"
                + "\nCliente: x", "Confirmar Eliminar",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if(num == 0){
//acciones
}
else{
//significa que pulsó no o que cerro la ventana
//acciones
}
```